# How to let static_assert treat pointer constant as integer constant

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

When use STM32 HAL(Hardware Abstract Layer) library, I like add _Static_assert to check MCU components clock source configed correctly even later the AF(alternative function) will be change. Such as follow:

```c
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    static_assert(DBG_UART==UART0, "cx32l003 hal: here need adjust.");
    __HAL_RCC_UART0_CLK_ENABLE();
    static_assert(DBG_TX_GPIO_Port==GPIOD, "cx32l003 hal: here need adjust.");
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

// both DBG_UART and UART0 refrence to same pointer constant:
#define DBG_UART UART0
#define UART0                       ((UART_TypeDef*)              UART0_BASE)
#define UART0_BASE                  0x40000000UL
```

But gcc complain `warning: expression in static assertion is not an integer constant expression [-Wpedantic]` when gcc compilation option `-Wpedantic` added.

Any way to tell gcc not complain such comparision?

Comment: I don't know why casting to `uint32_t` would work around the warning. According to the C specification, "Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an operand to the `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator."

Comment: These casts won't fix the problem of pointers not being integer constant expressions... I can't reproduce. What is the exact version of the compiler? You are compiling this with `#include <assert.h>` present, yes?

Comment: `Have any way to tell gcc not complain such comparision?` Do not use `-Wpedantic`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Not really advised in (embedded) systems, as dropping that compiler option will open the flood gates for all manner of non-standard GNU crap of diverse usefulness, with diverse presence/absence of documentation...

Comment: If `UART0_BASE` is an integer constant, perhaps you could use `#define DBG_UART_BASE UART0_BASE`, `#define DBG_UART ((UART_TypeDef*) DBG_UART_BASE)`, and check `DBG_UART_BASE==UART0_BASE` in the static assertions.

Comment: @IanAbbott That would probably mess up the function calls of the "HAL" instead since they assume that you pass along a pointer corresponding to the specific peripheral.

Comment: The way I sometimes deal with stuff like this is to type down a bunch of "is the program sane" assertions inside a `#ifdef DEBUG` switch somewhere early on and let the program hang up there in run-time. The programmer will still catch the problem early on while running through a debugger. Static assertions are pretty but they are just a tool, the important part is to spot bugs before they make it to the release/production build.

Comment: How is `UART0_BASE` defined? Please provide code

Comment: Yes, I was misled by vscode syntax check，cast to `uint32_t`  would not supress the warning. `#include <assert.h>` present. @Ian Abbott @Lundin

Comment: Use combine of `#ifdef DEBUG` and `dynamic assert` may be a good workabout for this, I will try it @Lundin